# How do I ignore special characters when tokenizing in NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk

I have the following string:

```
title = 'Tesla S&P Debut Comes All at Once'
```

When I tokenize this in NLTK, I get the following:

```
token = nltk.word_tokenize(title)
token
['Tesla', 'S', '&', 'P', 'Debut', 'Comes', 'All', 'at', 'Once']
```

Tokenizing splits `S&P` because of the `&`.

How can I prevent NLTK from splitting on particular special characters?

Comment: So you want to avoid splitting on `&` always?

Comment: Yes, because the strings I'm dealing with are headlines of news articles, which are often abbreviated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use regexp_tokenize from nltk where you can choose a regular expression to define seps

```
from nltk import regexp_tokenize
title = 'Tesla S&P Debut Comes All at Once'
tokens = regexp_tokenize(title, pattern=r"\s|[\.,;']", gaps=True)

print(tokens)
```

> ['Tesla', 'S&P', 'Debut', 'Comes', 'All', 'at', 'Once']